# Sorting selected rows in a datatable with CSS checkbox

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable with checkboxes similar to this [example](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html).

The checkboxes are made using the CSS `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements so the column holding them has no values.

I am programmatically selecting some rows when the user clicks on a button, but would like the selected rows to appear at the top of the table. This is mainly so that the user sees something happening, especially when the selected rows are in non-visible pages.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b22kx27s/2/

I've tried looking into custom sort function to bring the selected rows to the top but couldn't figure out how to do it since the column has no values.

Comment: Without some sort of data changing in that column, I'm unsure how you can get DataTables to sort by it when you check the box.  (Clever use of :before and :after to accomplish those checkboxes!)

Comment: Agree with cale_b  ... you have to store that state somewhere that can be referenced to the row data when internals of plugin do the custom sort. Could be stored in a data store outside the plugin data but makes it a bit trickier doing it that way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking at [this page](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html), I used an order function that for each column, checks if the line of each cell has the `selected` class:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-checkbox'] = function  ( settings, col )
{
  return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
    return $(td).closest('tr').hasClass('selected') ? '1' : '0';
  } );
}
```

Using `orderDataType: 'dom-checkbox'` in the `columnDefs` for the first columns allows to order by selection.

Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s65tjv0v/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-checkbox'] = function  ( settings, col )
{
  return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
    return $('input', td)[1].checked ? '1' : '0';
  } );
}
```

Using `orderDataType: 'dom-checkbox'` in the `columnDefs` for the first columns allows to order by selection.